# Wordpress Yoast plugin update seo title

Tags: php, html, wordpress, seo, title

I´ve been looking around to see where I can change the seo title in my database, but i cannot find my answer.

We changed names, and now all my seo titles look like:

PRODUCT_NAME bij OLD_NAME

Now I want to replace OLD_NAME by NEW_NAME in the database, or where ever Yoast plugin saves those titles. But I cannot seem to find where it is. Can somebody tell me where it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the SEO titles are stored in `wp_postmeta`. So i just did a query in the database like:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET  `meta_value` = REPLACE(  `meta_value` ,  'OLD_NAME',  'NEW_NAME' )
```

Hope it helps others too.